# Usestate has initial value of [Object, object]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The value of use State when put into the input value comes out to [Object, object] but in dev tools, it is shown empty.

```
 import { useState } from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

function Login() {

  const [input, setInput] = useState({
    email: ' ',
    password: ' '
  })
 
  return (
    <>
    <form className="form-group">
      <div className="input-group">
        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" id= 'email' name = 'email' className="form-input" value={input} />
      </div>
      <div className="input-group">
        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
        <input type="text" id='password' name='password' className="form-input" value={input}/>
      </div>
      <p>Don't have an Account? <Link>SignUp</Link> </p>
        <button className='btn'>LogIn</button>
    </form>
</>
  )
}

export default Login
```

I cant even use any function.

Comment: `value={input}` should be `value={input.email}` for email input field and `value={input.password}` for your password field, as you have set an object with keys `email` and `password` in useState

Comment: Your state is an object, so when you try to give the value of your input to "input" it is trying to give an object to your input field which expects a string. Instead try to use `value={input.email}` and `value={input.password}` in your input elements

Comment: yeah thx.  my brain is not braining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The value of use State when put into the input value comes out to [Object, object]**

This is because you need to access the object correctly. Instead of value=`{input}`, you need to use `value={input.email}`, and similarly for password `value={input.password}`

```
<input type="text" id= 'email' name = 'email' className="form-input" value={input.email} />
```

---

`useState()` sets the default state, and you have specified the default state as an empty string '', that's the reason the initial value will always be empty. You can assign something to check like

```
const [input, setInput] = useState({
    email: 'test_email',
    password: '******'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting the value of set as default in the input field you must call it by its key, not the whole object. Change `value = {input}` to `value = {input.email}` and `value={input.password}`.

The fields will not update when you will try type inside the input fields, you would need to specify `onChange={someEventHandleFunction}` where `someEventHandleFunction` will map the values to the provided keys.

Alternatively, you can also use two different `useState()` to handle email and password separately.